# NullPointerException and findViewById()

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception

Note: This is intended as a canonical question for a commonly seen problem here on Stack Overflow.

My Android app crashed. I [checked the stacktrace from the logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) and found that the cause is a `NullPointerException` at the line

```
myEditText.setText(myString);
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: @4castle This question is more specific. Of course, I should have found a way to include a link to that question in mine.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide more detail about your code. I think you didn't initialize myEditText correctly

something like this:

```
EditText myEditText = findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```

Answer (score 2):

you didn't initialize `myEditText` reference to any `EditText` Object in the activity which holds it..

kindly be sure you initialize it and you use that statement in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that `myEditText` has not been initialized correctly. First, you need to be sure that you call `findViewById()`. For example

```
myEditText = findViewById(R.id.text);
```

If you already did this, double-check that the resource id matches the one declared in the XML layout file for your activity or fragment.

Also, you may have forgot to call `setContentView()` in your activity's `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Also, If you try to get a reference for a `View` before calling `setContentView`

Comment: @jDawg Good one. I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

Remember one thing whenever you get null pointer exception in any findViewById it can only happens if id declared inside XML and java files are not matching or say from java side you are trying to access Id which don't even declared in XML side.

Another point i want to make is you are using setText() method and you are passing String object now keep in mind that it can also arise null pointer if it's a null object and don't have any value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Note that this is not the only reason for a NPE in this situation.

Comment: What is another reason? Can u please let me know

Comment: Please read the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

use "" and then append your string. its probably your myString returning null.

```
myEditText.setText("" + myString);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This is actually a fault in my contrived example.